# Recyclerview fragment inside fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-listview

Alsalm alikom

I have fragment A inside it fragment B
In fragment B there are recyclerview but it did not show
When move recyclerview to first fragment (A) it will show and work perfectly

Comment: show your code here

Comment: post your code plz!